# Alembic: Enforce value uniqueness across two values

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have the following table

```
mysql> describe table;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| value1         | varchar(2)  | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                |
| value2         | varchar(2)  | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| value3         | varchar(10) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to create an alembic rule, where `value1` and `value2` together create a key in the table. For example, the values

```
(id=1, value1="BA", value2="CN", value3="hello")
(id=2, value1="BA", value2="CN", value3="goodbye")
```

are the same (`value1` and `value2` match), but

```
(id=1, value1="BA", value2="CN", value3="hello")
(id=2, value1="BA", value2="US", value3="goodbye")
```

are not.

What would be the alembic `upgrade()` and `downgrade()` code for this be, using an `alembic.op` object?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your model has the definition of the following `UniqueConstraint`:

```
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mytable'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    value1 = Column(String(2), nullable=False)
    value2 = Column(String(2))
    value3 = Column(String(10))

    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint(value1, value2, name="mytable__uc_value1_value2"),
    )
```

The `def upgrade():` of alembic revision would then contain following command in order to create this unique constraint:

```
def upgrade():
    op.create_unique_constraint(
        "mytable__uc_value1_value2", "mytable", ["value1", "value2"]
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks van for the answer to upgrade. I also add the code to downgrade:

```html
from alembic import op


def upgrade():
    op.create_unique_constraint(
        "uc_table_name_column1_column2_column3", "table_name",  
         ["column1", "column2", "column3"], "schema_name"
    )

def downgrade():
    op.drop_constraint(
      "uc_table_name_column1_column2_column3", 
      "table_name", "unique", "schema_name"
    )
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31376955)